# Accessing a textbox in word document using NPOI library

Tags: asp.net-core, ms-word, textbox, npoi

Help me please
In short, I need to change textbox text inside word document, but I can't access textbox because inside XWPFDocument object there are only paragraphs and tables. I'm working on ASP.NET Core project and using NPOI library

I only managed to access list of paragraphs and tables of word document

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.